# Changing the object material without clicking on it

Tags: c#, unity

How can I change the object material automatically without clicking on it?  The object material should change based on a timer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it!

```
Invoke("ChangeMaterial", 2); // Time is 2 seconds

function ChangeMaterial () { 
/* Change Material */
}
```

Comment: ` public GameObject newSprite;
 
 private Vector3 currentSpritePosition;
 
 void Start(){
  
  newSprite.renderer.enabled = false;
  currentSpritePosition = transform.position;
  
  //then make it invisible
  renderer.enabled = false;
  
  //give the new sprite the position of the latter
  newSprite.transform.position = currentSpritePosition;
  
  //then make it visible
  newSprite.renderer.enabled = true;
 }

 void OnMouseExit(){
  //just the reverse process
  renderer.enabled = true;
  newSprite.renderer.enabled = false;
 }
`

Comment: the above code works in the form like when mouse is moved on the object,the material of the object is changing.How can I modifiy with the above code please help me out

Comment: This answer is being flagged automatically for being too short. Maybe expand on the `/*Change Material*/` part to actually change the material.